# postgresql trigger after insert or update or delete

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have table called mdl_user and I added a new columns for this table, the first one is called "LastOperation" and the second one "TimeStamp"

I need to create trigger after insert or update or delete and write the output as "I" or "U" or "D" at "LastOperation" column and the time when this action happenes at "TimeStamp" column

NOTE: All this stuff to be in the same table not to be triggered for another table

Comment: `TG_OP`- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER

Comment: You are talking about the same table? So that instead of actually deleting, you want to mark the row with 'D' in 'LastOperation'?

Comment: yes you are right, in the same table I want to write D or I or U for Delete or Insert or Update transaction with adding timestamp for column TimeStamp when this transaction of D or I or U happens

Comment: 1) You can't `DELETE` and have the row remain 2) You can't do what you want with an `AFTER` trigger, the action (I,U,D) will have happened by that time and you would not have a row left to add the `D` and timestamp.  What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Yes bro you are right, what if I want to trigger (I, U) to a column in the same table? is it possible ? and how ?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=postgresql+audit+trigger There is no question in your question BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want and still use standard DML (including delete). It does however require a little behind the scenes manipulation of database objects. What it involves doing your DML against not a table but an update-able view.

1. Add the new columns as usual to the table.
2. Rename the table. Say to mdl_user_tab.
3. Create a VIEW with the same name and definition as the old table. Simple select (no join) from new table name.
4. Create a trigger function which interprets the DML manipulates the actual table.
5. Create an INSTEAD trigger for all DML operations against the VIEW.

You now process everything against the view (most existing code will not require updating). But you may need some additional functionality for actually processing the table. See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa21cd654ebaea456bc08e16f84ab451).